# how do you sort data frame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have this data frame:

```
    Env location     lob grid  row     server    model  make slot ports connected disabled
0    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    1   3.0       1.0      5.0
1    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    2   2.0       3.0      3.0
2    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    3   0.0       0.0      2.0
3    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    4   8.0       7.0      1.0
4   Total      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    4   13.0      11.0     11.0
                                                                                           
6     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    10   6.0       5.0      0.0
7     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    1   8.0       4.0      0.0
8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    2  12.0       4.0      0.0
9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    3  10.0       2.0      0.0
8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    8  12.0       4.0      0.0
9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    9  10.0       2.0      0.0
10  Total     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    7   36.0      15.0      0.0
```

I need to sort this data frame by "model" and "Slot", Slot needs to start with 1 and in ascending order, Total needs to be at the end of each group of model.

For example model=IBM starts from 10, it needs to start with 1, 10 needs to be last number before total row. Total row always at the end of each group of model. Final data frame needs to look this:

print(df)

```
           Env location     lob grid  row     server    model  make slot ports connected disabled
    0    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    1   3.0       1.0      5.0
    1    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    2   2.0       3.0      3.0
    2    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    3   0.0       0.0      2.0
    3    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    4   8.0       7.0      1.0
    4   Total      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    4   13.0      11.0     11.0
                                                                                               

    7     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    1   8.0       4.0      0.0
    8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    2  12.0       4.0      0.0
    9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    3  10.0       2.0      0.0
    8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    8  12.0       4.0      0.0
    9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    9  10.0       2.0      0.0

         Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    10   6.0       5.0      0.0
    10  Total     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    7   36.0      15.0      0.0
```

I tried this:

```
df.sort(['model', 'slot'], ascending=[True, False])
```

I need Total at the end of each model group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a temp col indicating `Total`:

```
(df.assign(is_total=df['Env'].eq('Total'),
           slot=df['slot'].astype('Int64'))
   .sort_values(['model','is_total','slot'])
   .drop(columns='is_total')
)
```

Output:

```
      Env location     lob grid  row     server    model  make  slot  ports  connected  disabled
0    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor     1    3.0        1.0       5.0
1    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor     2    2.0        3.0       3.0
2    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor     3    0.0        0.0       2.0
3    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor     4    8.0        7.0       1.0
4   Total      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor     4   13.0       11.0      11.0
7     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     1    8.0        4.0       0.0
8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     2   12.0        4.0       0.0
9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     3   10.0        2.0       0.0
8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     8   12.0        4.0       0.0
9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     9   10.0        2.0       0.0
6     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    10    6.0        5.0       0.0
10  Total     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa     7   36.0       15.0       0.0
```

Comment: I get TypeError: Unhasahable type: 'list',

Comment: Total needs to be at the end of each group "model"

Comment: Yes, they're at the end of each `model` group due to sort on `is_total`.

Comment: based on your last answer, I still see 10 before 1 for model 10.

Comment: sorry for going back and forth. I tried that still 10 comes up before 1. It may be type issue. is there a way to convert it to int in your code?